# all the previously stored objects in an array are replaced with the newly inserted object at the end of array. why?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have been inserting objects in the array one by one from an array of objects. But whenever I insert a new object, previous objects are automatically replaced. I am executing the following code block:

```
  let slotsArray = [];
  let slotsObj = {}; 

  try {

    let slotsData = await Slots.find({ author: req.user._id });

    for (let j = 0; j < slotsData.length; j++) {
      slotsObj.teacher = `${slotsData[j].teacherName}`;
      slotsObj.sections = [`${slotsData[j].session}-${slotsData[j].section}`];
      slotsObj.subject = `${slotsData[j].subjectName}`;
      slotsObj.numLectures = `${slotsData[j].contactHours}`;
      slotsObj.numLabs = null;
      slotsArray.push(slotsObj);
    }
```

Comment: There is only one `slotsObj`. You neet to have `slotsObj = {};` at the top of the loop so that each iteration is a new object.

Comment: ohhh thanks! It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move  let slotsObj = {}; inside the for loop, so slotsObj will be a new reference at each iteration.